# Output path is shared between the same module error

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

When I try to compile any class in my project I get the error below:

```
Error scala: Output path .../eval/target/test-classes is shared between: Module 'eval' tests, Module 'eval' tests
      Output path .../eval/target/classes is shared between: Module 'eval' production, Module 'eval' production
      Please configure separate output paths to proceed with the compilation.
```

I've seen how to set the output path in IDEA and I've done it. But as the error claims that it is shared between the same module I couldn't solve it.

Obs.: Using Maven and IntelliJ IDEA.

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Problem solved!


I have reset backward and forward my git repository many times and close-reopen idea after some of it.

When finaly IDEA shows a red message at the right top while it was starting. It says something like: the project has already a eval module, and if I want to delete eval module. Yes, it was quite confusing, but I click on delete and my problem disappear.

I guess that for some reason I become with 2 eval modules and it delete one of it solving output path error.

Comment: I'm using SVN, but also solved this problem by calling "Cleanup" and reimporting my maven project into the Idea.

Comment: I was just fighting this problem for several hours until I realized that the parent versions referred by my sub-modules where not consistent. Fixing them solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

I have reset backward and forward my git repository many times and close-reopen idea after some of it. When finaly IDEA shows a red message at the right top while it was starting. It says something like: the project has already a eval module, and if I want to delete eval module. Yes, it was quite confusing, but I click on delete and my problem disappear. I guess that for some reason I become with 2 eval modules and it delete one of it solving output path error.

Comment: Same issue but it is quite scary as it asks you to delete a module when it appears as one.

Comment: Not quite the answer in my case, but close enough.  I had to disable some plugins that the IDEA was asking for because of project files checked in to version control.  The same pop-up type of notification came and asked if I'd like to disable the plugins.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I guess your fix amounts to opening `.idea/modules.xml` and deleting the duplicate modules.

Comment: I downvoted your answer since it is not the answer to the problem. look at what yonatan maman wrote.

Comment: Yes, restarting until it gets fixed shouldn't be the answer.

Answer (score 43):

all you need to do is:

- synchronize both modules (right click  > Synchronize)
- re-import pom.xml for both modules (right click > Maven > Re Import)

Enjoy

Answer (score 16):

Set up the output paths for your modules to different directories, as explained here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-module-compiler-output.html

`On Project "Open Module Settings" -> Modules -> Paths -> Output/Test path`

Comment: Excellent. I had to click on my project and then do this.

Comment: I found it's a Gradle plugin issue. Anytime you reimport the Gradle project, it overrides your choice and sets them back to the same.

Comment: If you apply the `idea` plugin you can configure the output dirs of your module(s), or set `inheritOutputDirs = true`, as described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html). Next time you reimport your project you won't lose your settings.

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this by selecting "Inherit project compile output path" in the Project Structure settings window.

[image]

Comment: this resets everytime you refresh the project

Comment: @habitats I have seen the same thing. :/

Answer (score 5):

1. `Files --> Invalidate caches and restart`
2. Close intellij
3. delete (extenrally from intellij) `.idea` folder (backup `runConfigurations` folder if you have one).
4. delete the `project.iml` file
5. Open intellij
6. Open the project again from `pom` or from `sbt` (or whatever source build tool you have.

Comment: Invalidate caches is the one that fixed it for me.  Required a *long* time .. but the result is worth it in the end.

Answer (score 4):

I had this happen with the root module in a multi-module project. Since the root module was just a placeholder, it didn't actually contain any code, but IDEA still complained that it was sharing an output path (`[project]/build`) between test and production.

The fix was to add

```
plugins {
  id "java"
}
```

at the top of the root `build.gradle` file (applying the otherwise unnecessary Java plugin) and reimporting the project. This allowed IDEA to pick up the Java-default `[project]/build/classes/main` and `[project]/build/classes/test` output directories.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is the only one that keeps you from having to manually fix the problem whenever your dependencies change.

Comment: My feeling is that this is basically an IDEA bug, but I've been too lazy to file it.

Comment: Alternatively you can apply the `idea` plugin and configure your root module so that `inheritOutputDirs = true`. This requires slightly more configuration but feels a little more intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Open up the module settings and look for errors. Fix said errors and everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

For a Spark project, the IDE created `_2.11` versions of SBT modules. I had to delete them by hand.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuG5S.png)

Idea itself reports an error, the prompt is already very obvious, calm analysis can solve;
Open Project Structure --> modules.   Delete or reconfigure outputPath,The computer is the most honest

Answer (score 0):

This is really a response to @habitat's comment on @Corey Klein 's answer.  If someone with enough reputation wants to edit, please go ahead...

I had the same problem with the setting being reset every time I refreshed the project.  My solution (with Gradle, although I'm guessing there is an equivalent Maven plugin) was to add

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For gradle, I delete the .idea folder and reopen the project. Everything is recovery.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 differently named versions of the same module and needed to delete one to avoid this clash. This is what worked for me:

In IntelliJ IDEA go to `File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Your Project -> Paths`

Ensure each Modules "Output path" and "Test output path" locations are unique across all your modules.
If you have more than one module with the same paths, you can specify unique paths for every module or as in my case, delete the module that you do not require as it was a duplicate of an existing module

Answer (score -1):

I face the same issue i resolve this by deleting  .iml2 from the module which was created by intellij.