# Scala (SBT) compile error: separate output paths (production, tests)

Tags: scala, compilation

I have the same compile error on IntelliJ and Eclipse Scala:

> "Error:scalac: Output path C:\workspaces\ScalaProgFun\forcomp\bin is
>   shared between: Module 'progfun-forcomp' production, Module
>   'progfun-forcomp' tests Please configure separate output paths to
>   proceed with the compilation. TIP: you can use Project Artifacts to
>   combine compiled classes if needed."

Can someone help me with this, please?
I have no idea how SBT works!

This error happens on this project:
http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/progfun/assignments/forcomp.zip

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In IntelliJIDEA you can try to use File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Your Project -> Paths
Specify different paths for test and output (if you have more than one module - you can try to specify unique paths for every module)

Comment: Great! thank you very much.
I followed your advise and made some research, I could find this link: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-compiler-output.html and configure the right paths for my project

Comment: Though the paths for test and output were indicated seperately, i was still getting the same error. Then i unchecked the "exclude output paths" and it compiled. Then i checked the  it again and it was still working. It may be a ide error, i guess.

Comment: A simpler way IMOH is presented in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21418406/3506427. Just resync and reimport the maven modules

Comment: @bogdan.rusu so you’re basically saying it’s simpler to just use Maven instead of SBT? :-D

Comment: @dk14 No, I just wanted to say that a re-sync of the modules might also work. In my example I use Maven, but it seems an Idea issue here. Maybe my words didn't reflect that but that is basically what I wanted to say.

Comment: @bogdan.rusu so, you didn’t mean “reimport maven modules” when you wrote that, okay :). Anyways your link helped because it had two more universal and robust approaches in other answers: inheritance and cache invalidation.

Comment: @dk14 Yeah, I should have dropped that phrase - it generated some confusion :)

Comment: this did not help me because whatever settings i change, it gets overwritten when i do gradle update of the module .how have you guys solved this

Comment: @MohammedRafeeq this one is for SBT (not graddle). It used to have a plugin that generates .idea project manually long time ago